# Odoo - Click event customization in list view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have create a list view with the help of psql query with `_auto = False`. So there is not model registered against this. Now i want to customize this click event on the records that whenever a user click on any records i want to pass an order_id and then redirect user to that particular order detail screen.

**Edit**

View

```
<odoo>
<data>
    <record id="amgl_dashboard_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Dashboard</field>
        <field name="model">amgl.dashboard</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree default_order="state desc" decoration-bf ="state in ('expecting','pending','completed')" decoration-info="state=='expecting'" decoration-danger="state=='pending'" decoration-succes="state=='completed'" string="Dashboard" create="false" edit="false">
                <field name="order_id" invisible="1"/>
                <button name="view_record" type="object" string="View Record" custom="click" class="oe_highlight"/>
                <field name="first_name"/>
                <field name="last_name"/>
                <field name="account_number"/>
                <field name="product"/>
                <field name="quantity"/>
                <field name="total_weight"/>
                <field name="state"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
</odoo>
```

.Py

```
class Dashboard(models.Model):
_name = 'amgl.dashboard'
_auto = False

@api.multi
def view_record(self):
    print self

@api.model_cr
def init(self):
    tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'dashboard')
    self._cr.execute("""
            CREATE or REPLACE VIEW amgl_dashboard AS (

                SELECT 
                    row_number() OVER () AS id,
                    c.name AS first_name,
                    c.last_name AS last_name,
                    c.account_type AS account_type,
                    c.account_number AS account_number,                        
                    (select name from amgl_products where id = ol.products) AS product,
                    ol.quantity AS quantity,
                    (CASE
                    WHEN (select weight_unit from amgl_products where id = ol.products) = 'oz'
                           THEN
                        (select weight_per_piece from public.amgl_products where id = ol.products) * ol.quantity
                    WHEN (select weight_unit from amgl_products where id = ol.products) = 'gram'
                           THEN
                        ((select weight_per_piece from public.amgl_products where id = ol.products) / 28.34952) * ol.quantity
                    WHEN (select weight_unit from amgl_products where id = ol.products) = 'pounds'
                           THEN
                        ((select weight_per_piece from amgl_products where id = ol.products) * 16) * ol.quantity
                    WHEN (select weight_unit from amgl_products where id = ol.products) = 'kg'
                           THEN
                        ((select weight_per_piece from amgl_products where id = ol.products) / 0.02834952) * ol.quantity
                    ELSE 0.0
                    END) AS total_weight,
                    o.state AS state,
                    o.id  AS order_id
                    FROM amgl_order AS o
                    INNER JOIN amgl_customer AS c ON c.id = o.customer_id
                    INNER JOIN amgl_order_line AS ol ON ol.order_id = o.id
            )""")

name = fields.Char()
first_name = fields.Char(string="First Name")
last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name")
account_type = fields.Char(string="Account Type")
account_number = fields.Char(string="Account Number")
product = fields.Char(string="Product")
quantity = fields.Float(string="Quantity")
total_weight = fields.Float(string="Total Weight")
state = fields.Selection([('expecting', 'Expecting'), ('pending', 'Pending'),
                          ('completed', 'Completed'), ('waiting', 'Waiting For Approval')],
                         'Status', default='expecting')
order_id = fields.Integer(string="Order Id")
```

Action

```
<record id="amgl.dashboard_action_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Dashboard</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">amgl.dashboard</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            <!-- Add Text Here -->
          </p><p>
            <!-- More details about what a user can do with this object will be OK -->
          </p>
        </field>
  </record>
```

**Debugger**

`Self._context`

[image: self._context]

`Self`

[image: Self]

Comment: Why did you do so without any Odoo model definition?

Comment: I doesn't mean that i do have a model defination same as the query returns. I was saying that `_auto=False` doesn't create table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of ways this could *possibly* work. I'm not 100% certain either of them will, but I'll give you the general ideas.

## XML Only Solution

George has the main idea correct - you need to create an action to manage what you're wanting to do.

The important distinction is that you seem to want the list view to display one model (`amgl.dashboard`) but the form view to display another (`sale.order`)

Normally, I would suggest you create a `button` and display it in the list view to take the user directly to the sales order form. However, you may also be able to use a standard `act_window` action with the help of `src_model`.

**Example from core:**

Odoo uses the button below to invoke the action, which results in the user being able to go to the `stock.location` form view and go to the `product.product` list. You are essentially wanting to do the opposite of this with different models and without the button.

```
<button string="Products"
        class="oe_stat_button"
        icon="fa-filter" name="%(act_product_location_open)d" type="action"
        context="{'location_id': active_id}"
        />

<act_window
    id="act_product_location_open"
    name="Products"
    src_model="stock.location"
    res_model="product.product"
    context="{'location': active_id, 
              'search_default_real_stock_available': 1, 
              'search_default_virtual_stock_available': 1,                     
              'search_default_virtual_stock_negative': 1, 
              'search_default_real_stock_negative': 1}"/>
```

## Python Solution:

Assuming your `view_record` method is being called already, you can return the "View Sales Order form" action directly from the method itself.

```
# Make sure these imports are called in your file
# If you are on Odoo 9 or earlier, you must use openerp instead of odoo
from odoo import _
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError


class Dashboard(models.Model):
    _name = 'amgl.dashboard'
    _auto = False 

    @api.multi
    def view_record(self):
        """Return a Window Action to view the Sales Order form"""
        self.ensure_one()
        action = self.env.ref('sale.action_orders')
        form = self.env.ref('sale.view_order_form', False)

        if not (action or form):
            raise ValidationError(_("Sales Orders Action or Form not found!"))
        return {
            'name': action.name,
            'help': action.help,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'views': [(form_id.id, 'form')]
            'res_model': action.res_model,
            'res_id': self._context.get('id'),
            'target': 'current',
            'context': {},
        }
```

Comment: ok, So i kind of started working but not fully. I am following python approach now as you can see i have `order_id` in my model. But when i try to redirect on button click i got error at ` 'res_id': self.order_id,` and it says that `InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

Comment: also if i try to fetch this `self.order_id` in debugger it still gives me error. But if i show order_id in listview then it shows properly that means value is coming from behind. But there is something else wrong. Can you point at that ?

Comment: @Ancient Can you check in the debugger to see what `self` is and what context (`self._context` usually) is?

Comment: `self` is a dashboard class object having all the properties but no values against them and for `self._context` let me check

Comment: Is `self` an empty recordset, single record, or multiple recordsets?

Comment: check my question update. I added screenshots of both

Comment: @Ancient Can you try updating your code to temporarily luse a hard-coded `order_id` instead of `self.order_id` to see if it works as expected? Like `'res_id': 123` or whatever is a valid Order ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153278/discussion-between-ancient-and-travisw).

Answer (score 0):

When you click a record on a `listview` an action is executed that moves you from the `listview` to a `formview.

There always exists a default action but if you want to pass some extra parameters you have to define your own. For a concrete example take a look at the `sale.action_quotations` action. This action moves the user from view1 to view2 (list to form for example)

https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/10.0/addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml#L518

```
<record id="action_quotations" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    ...
    <field name="context">{'hide_sale': True}</field>
    ...
</record
```

This action is responsible for moving the user in Quotations between views. See how the context is passed. You only need `tree,form` on the `view_mode` here.

Comment: and how to invoke this action on click of row in list-view ?

Comment: It is automatically invoked, you do not need to do anything else.

Comment: check my question update. I added all code.Now can you let me know what changes i need to do in-order to redirect user to another model's detail page on click of button which is placed inside every row